# Store won't work after Windows Phone 8.1 update

Tags: store, 8.1

Today I updated Preview for Devs Windows Phone 8.1. After update I hit store icon and gone exploring changes. There were some other updates and after I finished downloading all of them, my store just refuses to cooperate. Sometimes it's saying that connection isn't available, but mostly it gives the error code `805a01f7`

[image]

What can I do about it. Did anyone faced this problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a temporary issue with the Windows Store

Comment: @RowlandShaw, is there a place you can point us all to so that the next time such an issue comes up, we know whether it's a temporary issue or a real problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same problem here, I'm guessing the servers are being [hammered](http://www.wpcentral.com/service-alert-windows-phone-store-down), III still have about 59apps to go yet. Know how you feel, don't stress, I'm gonna just leave it for now and try later

Comment: Not related to the update, just an issue with the store for some people.

Comment: Is it working now? If so, can you edit it and provide a more definite answer e.g. it was an intermittent issue?

Comment: I can confirm you just have to give it some time. Happened to me after initial 8.1 update, and again after switching to USA region to enable Cortana. Second time around, the issue resolved much quicker.

Comment: Even I had same problem. But, just check you set the Location settings correctly, language, keyboard etc. Restart the phone and check again. It worked for me.

Comment: There was an announcement about it on the Microsoft support forums